# c# - Dealing with lots of data

Tags: c#

Iam looking for a way to tranfer a lot data to a database table. I have a class with over 100 properties and I would like to know a good way to transfer all the data to the table.

I have a class where I assign each property a value. What is the best to group the properties and send to another class for inserting into the table??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe "a lot of data". E record with 100 fields is not that much. But if you have hundreds of megabytes you want to store at a time, then that's another story.

Comment: From a sanity (not performance) point of view, some kind of ORM is going to help with large classes. However, 100 properties sounds a lot, and so it might be worth looking to see if you are really modelling things in the most efficient way in the first place.

Comment: The most efficient way for dealing with 100 of fields is what iam looking for :S. I dont know how to set them up in a efficient way so I can then put them in the table.

Answer (score 2):

My point would be batch all INSERT statement in a single trip to the database server.

I don't know if you're using some OR/M, but I'll assume you're with plain ADO.NET.

You can achieve that by first programatically creating a plain text file and append all INSERT statements, and then use it as a command text of a IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery implementation.

Doing in batch is important because you can send the entire list of INSERT statements to the database server in a single trip and connection, and let database server optimize storing your data, so your application will be free to do another tasks.

I suggest you that batch insertion task should by asynchronous (that's in another thread than main application one) in order to avoid freezing user interface. Perhaps it's a console application, so just use main thread.

Comment: When I klick the button that assigns the value to the properties the user interface frezes. Is there eny good way devide all the fields into two or more groups so that then add them to the table??

Comment: Just read my answer man! :) Curiously, I suggested you a way of avoiding UI freezing. You'll need to learn multithreading, won't you?

Comment: The reason my application froze was just because some of the fields were NULL. With adding NullReferenceException to the catch frase, the application doesnt freeze and loads all of the fields without eny problem. It takes about 2 minutes to add all the fields to a datagriview :S

Comment: Well, then maybe you need to send chunks of batches? 1000, 1000, 1000 and so on, and after storing 1000, update that data grid so it can be populated in real time.

Comment: You are right, I do need multithreading :S. I suck at that :P

Comment: Hahaha, well, check articles about .NET 4.0 Task API and maybe you can be better in asynchronous programming :)

Comment: Is it possible to devide all the fields into sperate classed so and group them again?? so i wont have to use multithreading

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that you have an class with plenty of fields and you want to automatically copy the value to your ORM data type that you can then insert to the DB? If so, try looking into AutoMapper, it is brilliant.
http://automapper.codeplex.com/